# Grid graph embedding not being kept after Vertex deletion

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I have a grid, and I delete a vertex, while keeping the embedding:

```
g = GridGraph[{15, 15}];
g = SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g]];
g = VertexDelete[g, {50}];
```

Before deleting the vertices, I check their graph embedding:

I check the graph embedding before and after vertex deletion, via the code:

```
GraphEmbedding[g][[49]]
GraphEmbedding[g][[64]]
```

The result is that beforehand, the output was "{4., 4.}" and "{5., 4.}". After vertex deletion it is "{4., 4.}" and "{5., 5.}".

For some reason however the embedding is visually the same. Then why is this an issue? I use the following code to draw directed edges of a given graph path:

```
graphArrow[edge_] := 
 Arrow[{GraphEmbedding[g][[edge[[1]]]], 
   GraphEmbedding[g][[edge[[2]]]]}]
HighlightGraph[g, someData, VertexSize -> Medium, 
  Epilog -> {Black, Arrowheads[.03], 
    graphArrow /@ someData}];
```

The result is that some of the arrows drawn in Epilog look "diagonal", due to this graph embedding artefact. Example:

```
HighlightGraph[g, 49 -> 64, VertexSize -> Medium, 
 Epilog -> {Black, Arrowheads[.03], graphArrow /@ {49 -> 64}}]
```

How can I fix this and correctly draw directed edges?

Comment: I see, you can use `PropertyValue[{g, (*vertex*)}, VertexCoordinates]` instead of `GraphEmbedding[g][[edge[[1]]]]`

Comment: or GraphEmbedding[g][[VertexIndex[g, edge[[1]]]]]